# PHP Curl does not return a values from url

Tags: php, curl

i am using above function to retrieve the two urls , second one works when i am retriving google or other websites, but below things is not getting any response. but when i enter the url in browser i am seeing the response.. can you guide me to fix this issue?

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}


$response=file_get_contents_curl('http://XX.XX.XX.XX:YYYYY/Request?Mob=999999999&Message=Rr+vodafone+999999999+10+1234&myTxId=10');
echo "<br/>respnse  is...".$response;

$response=file_get_contents_curl('http://www.google.com');
echo "<br/>website respond is...".$response;
```

Edit:
Issue is with Port number i am trying to access 8090 is not enabled in my server. when i enabled it for outgoing it was working...  Thanks every one for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0');
```

Comment: Thank you, i can able to receive data from web pages, when i tried the url with ip address its not working...

Comment: @PHPLearner Are you able to access the URL with IP address using your browser?

Comment: @PHPLearner You can not always access websites using their IP addresses. For example, I have one server (178.79.180.95) which is running http://cotpi.com/ and http://mathb.in/. Both domains are mapped to 178.79.180.95. I've configured Apache server in a manner such that you if you access URLs with the domain names, you'll get the websites. But if you try to access http://178.79.180.95/ , you'll get a different default page. Some websites may be configured so that you don't get anything on trying to access it with IP address.

Comment: @Susam Pal, Thanks for responding to my queries. actually i am not accessing the website, its SMS gateway server , issue is 8090 outgoing port is not enabled in my server :( , i got to know this after trying hard for 2 days.. any ways.. Learning in the fire is Good ... you have a great day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find error give this code before curl close:--

```
echo "Curl Error :--" . curl_error($ch);
```

if no error found do like this:-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

then

```
print_r($result);
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you, i can able to receive data from web pages, when i tried the url with ip address its not working